# TypeScript what is the generic argument on the right side of statement

Tags: typescript, generics

What is the `<R>` called in TypeScript? Note that it's like a `derived` type from the passed argument. I cannot find any documentation on this.
The generic section only explains the left side `<S>`.

```
type F<S> = <R>(fn: (s: S) => R) =>  R;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the name of the inner generic is or if it has a special name, but it's the generic type of the function that you call that you pass the callback `fn` to. It's easier to see what's going on if we actually implement this type:

```
// This is now `<R>(fn: (s: number) => R)`
const foo: F<number> = cb => cb(1);
// num is a number
const bar = foo<string>(num => num.toString());
// invalid because `num` is a number which does not have `length`
const baz = foo<string>(num => num.length);
// invalid because we're returning a boolean instead of a string
const quux = foo<string>(num => !!num);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know what the use case is. It's very useful but I was hoping to see at least a mention of it somewhere officially.